# NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9825) Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1205

Tags: ios, https, afnetworking

```
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9825)
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1205 "服务器“10.100.5.105”不接受证书。" UserInfo={NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=<SecTrustRef: 0x1701042f0>, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9825, NSUnderlyingError=0x17024dc80 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1205 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=1, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust=<SecTrustRef: 0x1701042f0>, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9825, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9825, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates=(
    "<cert(0x101973200) s: taxappbs i: taxappca>"
)}}, NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey=(
    "<cert(0x101973200) s: taxappbs i: taxappca>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=服务器“10.100.5.105”不接受证书。, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://10.100.5.105:6443/entry, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://10.100.5.105:6443/entry, NSErrorClientCertificateStateKey=1}
```

I request a `https` server with a certificate using `AFNetworking 3.x`. It tells me that the sever rejected the certificate. Anyone knows how to fix it?

"服务器" = "server"

"不接受证书" = "reject certificate"

```
private static let manager: AFHTTPSessionManager = {
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        config.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 10
        let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager(sessionConfiguration: config)
        manager.requestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer(writingOptions: .prettyPrinted)
        manager.responseSerializer = AFJSONResponseSerializer(readingOptions: .allowFragments) // AFHTTPResponseSerializer()
        manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = ["application/json", "text/json", "text/JavaScript", "text/html", "text/plain", "image/png"]
        let policy = AFSecurityPolicy(pinningMode: .certificate)
        policy.allowInvalidCertificates = true
        policy.validatesDomainName = false
        policy.pinnedCertificates = AFSecurityPolicy.certificates(in: .main)
        manager.securityPolicy = policy
        return manager
    }()
```

This is my code.

Answer (score 0):

Your app server should support TLS 1.2. Because on iOS 11+, the HTTPS use the TLSv1.2 to shake hand and create HTTP session. Configure your server's Tomcat or Nginx to accept the TLSv1.2.